# need help on regex or string replace

Tags: c#, regex, string

I want to replace all the content between this block with empty string,what's the better way to do it.Before replacing string the content would look like

```
 Customer Request Message......
[[REQUEST_Data]]
KEY=VALUE
KEY=VALUE
KEY=VALUE
[[/REQUEST_Data]]
```

After replacing the content would become
   Customer Request Message......
All the content between [[REQUEST_Data]] [[/REQUEST_Data]] must be replaced with empty string and also both the tag is also replace with empty string.

Comment: So basically you want the message to be transformed into "Customer Request Message......"?  Everything else is removed?

Comment: You are right Tim I have just tried the regex on this link [link](http://regexr.com?36h5u)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var regex = @"\[\[REQUEST_Data\]\](\n|\r|\r\n|.)*\[\[\/REQUEST_Data\]\]"
var replaced = Regex.Replace(input, regex, "");
```

Comment: My actual content is
Subject: RE: Job
Whoa!  Hold on.  I have a job scheduled at 5:30 which mails out
a report to key tech staff.  Could you please push it back an hour?
Danny
-------- Original Message --------
From: Jim 
Sent: Tuesday, October 16, 2007 9:40 AM
To: Danny 
Subject: Job
I'm going to suspend the mail service for approx. thirty
minutes tonight, starting at 5pm, to install some updates
and important fixes.
[[REQUEST_Data]]
KEY=VALUE
KEY=VALUE
KEY=VALUE
[[/REQUEST_Data]]
Jim

Comment: What does "both the tag is also replace with empty string" mean? Can you clarify the question?

Comment: tag  means [[REQUEST_Data]] [[/REQUEST_Data]] should also be ripped off .I am trying your regex on this link [link](http://regexr.com?36h5u)

Comment: I figured-out what the problem was. The dot doesn't match new lines in C#. This version should work. I tested it with http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx